# Does selectList retain value after user changes it from one value to other without saving

Tags: controller, selectlist

I have a VF page where I have created picklist using SelectList and SelectOption. I have written certain conditions depending on which it populates a value in it. Now if any user changes it, will the SelectList variable now hold the latest value which was changed by user? I want to perform some actions based on the value of SelectList.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. Can you please provide some code of what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you are binding the value for `selectList`. The value will be updated as soon as the form is submitted so when you press a button, at that moment, your controller will have the new value.

If you want to perform any operation based on previous value, then you can store it as a hidden field in the UI.

Please note that after the page renders, the controller is kind of destroyed. It is recreated from `ViewState` once you submit a request. So there is no retention in the controller.